# What does notifyOnNetworkStatusChange do exactly?

Tags: apollo-client

I had an issue where the `loading` property was not true when performing a `refetch`. I read somewhere `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` to true would fix this.

However we've notice after using this property we have some use case where we end up in infinite `refetch` loop with no good explanation.

Can someone explain exactly what the `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` do exactly on the useQuery hook? When should you use it, is there a particular `fetch-policy` you need to use in conjunction to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` is to allow us check the current `networkStatus` of your `useQuery`, which is a number. Then based on the `networkStatus` variable we can choose our own strategy to `render` the current component.

**Important Note:**
`loading` will be `undefined` without `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true`

The following code is from
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states

```
import { NetworkStatus } from '@apollo/client';

function DogPhoto({ breed }) {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery(
    GET_DOG_PHOTO,
    {
      variables: { breed },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    },
  );

  if (networkStatus === NetworkStatus.refetch) return 'Refetching!';
  if (loading) return null;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={data.dog.displayImage} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
      <button onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you noticed the code

`if (networkStatus === NetworkStatus.refetch) return 'Refetching!'`, which means when `refetch()` is called the DogPhoto component will change to `Retching!` until it's done.

The below link explained meaning of each number in `networkstatus`.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/src/core/networkStatus.ts#L4

It's used to reflect the current status of your `useQuery`. Then based on the status, you can do further action upon it in case if things failed, but I believe you can always create your own solution without it.